# Finding moments of the untruncated distribution from the moments of the truncated one

Tags: r, moments, truncated-normal-distribution

I would like to get the moments of a normal distribution from the moments of a two-sided truncated normal distribution in R.

Their formulas are available on the [truncated normal distribution Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

Basically, they follow the form:
$$E(X|\ a<X<b) = f(\mu, \sigma)$$
$$Var(X|\ a<X<b) = f(\mu, \sigma)$$

with $$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$ and $a$, $b$ the boundaries of the distribution.

Is it possible to get the inverse equations on R:
$$\mu = f(E(X|\ a<X<b), Var(X|\ a<X<b))$$
$$\sigma = f(E(X|\ a<X<b), Var(X|\ a<X<b))$$

I already had an estimation of those parameters with maximum likelihood approach but I was wondering if an analytical solution was possible.

Comment: To get the "is distributed" sign in Latex you need `\sim` rather than `~`.

Comment: When you write "Is it possible to get the inverse equations on R", note that pure programming questions are off-topic here (see our [help/on-topic]), but since you have an underlying statistical question I think this is fine.

Comment: Given that $a$ and $b$ are known, I believe the Wikipedia equations constitute a system of 2 nonlinear equations in the 2 unknowns ($\mu$ and $\sigma$). Presuming we're not in a degenerate case (I haven't looked into the criteria), that should be solvable by numerical methods in R (solve as system of nonlinear equations or as a nonlinear least squares problem). It should be possible in principle to solve these equations "analytically", but I believe that would involve defining new functions whose numerical evaluation would require the means previously described, so it would be somewhat vacuous

Comment: Your title mentions "inverse moments", but that's not what you're asking about; you're asking about finding moments of the untruncated distribution from the moments of the truncated one. Inverse moments are something else (e.g. the first inverse moment of $X$ is $E(\frac{1}{X})$). Please fix your post.

Comment: We cannot reasonably expect the moments of a truncated distribution to bear any relationship whatsoever to the moments of the original distribution.  This is because truncation removes all information about at least one tail, which--because it covers arbitrarily high values--could change all moments by arbitrary amounts. As an example, a Cauchy distribution has *no* odd moments and *infinite* even moments, whereas the moments of *any* truncated version (truncated high and low) will exist and be finite.