# Analytically derive standard deviation of parent normal distribution (with known mean) from moments of the truncated normal distribution

Tags: moments, truncated-normal-distribution, analytical

Given $\sigma_t$ and $\mu_t$ of a truncated normal distribution, as well as $\mu_p$ of the parent normal distribution, I would like to analytically compute the standard deviation $\sigma_p$ of the parent normal distribution.

A similar question has been asked [before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220935/finding-moments-of-the-untruncated-distribution-from-the-moments-of-the-truncate), without a solution. I want to give it another try though, also by specifying some constraints that apply in my case:

- I'm specifically interested in the normal distribution and not a generic approach to truncated distributions
- I assume knowing $\mu_p$
- For the truncation of the lower tail I'm only interested in the case $a=0$
- I also would be fine with a solution for the case of a truncation of the lower tail only (i.e. $a=0$); the two-sided truncation case with an arbitrary $b>0$ would also be of interest to me though.
- An approximate analytical solution is fine

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) I got for the one-sided truncation of the lower tail:

$\sigma_t^2=\sigma_p^2\left[1 + \alpha\frac{\phi(\alpha)}{Z} - \left(\frac{\phi(\alpha)}{Z}\right)^2\right]$

with $\;Z=1-\Phi(\alpha)$ and $\alpha=(a-\mu_p)/\sigma_p\;$ (i.e. $\alpha=-\mu_p/\sigma_p$ in my case).

(The two-sided case has a similar structure)

So essentially, I'm looking for an (approximate) analytical inverse of the form $\sigma_p=f(\mu_p,\sigma_t)$.

There is a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2015.05.006) which may be relevant in this context, but it exceeds my mathematical understanding, so I am not sure whether it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I ended up doing function fitting on simulated data. In particular, I was interested in the case of truncating at $a=0$ and $b=1$. The typical relationship between $\sigma_p$ and $\sigma_t$ depends on $\mu_p$ and looks as follows:

[image: Relationship between the parent and truncated standard deviation]

I compared a couple of [sigmoid-type functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples) and ended up with a function of the type $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Two more facts one can use:

- The asymptotic $\sigma_t$ is the standard deviation of a uniform distribution over the interval $[a=0; b=1]$, which is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(b-a)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$.
- The problem is symmetric around 0.5. I decided to fit on the interval [0.5; 1] as it avoids the special case $\mu_p=0$.

The final fitting function for $\sigma_t$ was:

$f(\sigma_p, \mu_p; \alpha, \beta)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\frac{\beta\mu_p^\alpha\sigma_p}{\sqrt{1 + (\beta\mu_p^\alpha \sigma_p)^2}}$

or by means of inversion: $\sigma_p=\frac{1}{\beta\mu_p^\alpha\sqrt{\frac{1}{12\sigma_t^2}-1}}$

..for which I obtained the parameters $\alpha=-0.712$ and $\beta=3.137$ by least square minimization. The fits look as follows:

[image: Function fit]

There's obviously still room for improvement.

**Update:**

$
f(\sigma_p, \mu_p; \alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2, \theta)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\frac{\beta_1\mu_p^{\alpha_1}\sigma_p}{\sqrt{1 + (\beta_1\mu_p^{\alpha_1} \sigma_p)^2}} & \text{if $\mu_p<\theta$}\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\tanh(\beta_2\mu_p^{\alpha_2}\sigma_p) & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$

or by means of inversion:

$
\sigma_p=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\beta_1\mu_p^{\alpha_1}\sqrt{\frac{1}{12\sigma_t^2}-1}} & \text{if $\mu_p<\theta$}\\
\frac{1}{\beta_2\mu_p^{\alpha_2}}\text{arctanh}(2\sqrt{3}\sigma_t) & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$

.. with $\alpha_1=-0.151$, $\beta_1=4.154$, $\alpha_2=-1.017$, $\beta_2=2.478$, $\theta=0.738$ works better:

[image]